# Iterating collections inside collections in Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

if I iterate every `user.id` inside the `user` collection I get every user.id printed out correctly:

```
user_ref = db.collection(u'users')
for user_collection in user_ref.get():
    print(user_collection.id, file = sys.stderr)
```

Now, when I try to iterate a collections inside each one of the documents inside the user collection, the original iteration that prints`user.id` does not run completely:

```
user_ref = db.collection(u'users')
for user_collection in user_ref.get():
    print(user_collection.id, file = sys.stderr)
    s2_ref = user_ref.document(user_collection.id).collection(u'preferences')
    for s2 in s2_ref.get():
        try:
            print(s2.id, file = sys.stderr)
        except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
            pass
```

I have included an exception to bypass empty collections.

How can I complete the iteration correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I just had to create an array for the first set of results, and then iterate each id separately:

```
    user_id_array = []
    for user_collection in user_ref.get():
        user_id_array.append(user_collection.id)
    for user_id in user_id_array:
        try:
            suscription_ref = doc_ref.document(user_id).collection(u'suscriptions').document(user_id).get()
            print(suscription_ref.id,file = sys.stderr)
        except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
            pass
```

It takes more time, but it'll get you there.